# React: convert createClass to ES6 class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to convert code with createClass to ES6 classes. I'm having some trouble when it comes to the class with the getInitialState function.

Below is the code I am trying to convert:

```
var StockRow = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var lastClass = '',
            changeClass = 'change-positive',
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top';
        if (this.props.stock === this.props.last) {
            lastClass = this.props.stock.change < 0 ? 'last-negative' : 'last-positive';
        }
        if (this.props.stock.change < 0) {
            changeClass = 'change-negative';
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom';
        }
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.stock.symbol}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.open}</td>
                <td className={lastClass}>{this.props.stock.last}</td>
                <td className={changeClass}>{this.props.stock.change} <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.high}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.low}</td>              
            </tr>
        );
    }
});

var StockTable = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var items = [];
        for (var symbol in this.props.stocks) {
            var stock = this.props.stocks[symbol];
            items.push(<StockRow key={stock.symbol} stock={stock} last={this.props.last} />);
        }
        return (
            <div className="row">
            <table className="table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Symbol</th>
                        <th>Open</th>
                        <th>Last</th>
                        <th>Change</th>
                        <th>High</th>
                        <th>Low</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        var stocks = {};
        feed.watch(['MCD', 'BA', 'BAC', 'LLY', 'GM', 'GE', 'UAL', 'WMT', 'AAL', 'JPM']);
        feed.onChange(function(stock) {
            stocks[stock.symbol] = stock;
            this.setState({stocks: stocks, last: stock});
        }.bind(this));
        return {stocks: stocks};
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <StockTable stocks={this.state.stocks} last={this.state.last}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is what I have for the first two:

```
class StockRow extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }
    render: function () {
        var lastClass = '',
            changeClass = 'change-positive',
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top';
        if (this.props.stock === this.props.last) {
            lastClass = this.props.stock.change < 0 ? 'last-negative' : 'last-positive';
        }
        if (this.props.stock.change < 0) {
            changeClass = 'change-negative';
            iconClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom';
        }
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.stock.symbol}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.open}</td>
                <td className={lastClass}>{this.props.stock.last}</td>
                <td className={changeClass}>{this.props.stock.change} <span className={iconClass} aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.high}</td>
                <td>{this.props.stock.low}</td>              
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class StockTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }
    render: function () {
        var items = [];
        for (var symbol in this.props.stocks) {
            var stock = this.props.stocks[symbol];
            items.push(<StockRow key={stock.symbol} stock={stock} last={this.props.last} />);
        }
        return (
            <div className="row">
            <table className="table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Symbol</th>
                        <th>Open</th>
                        <th>Last</th>
                        <th>Change</th>
                        <th>High</th>
                        <th>Low</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, I am unsure how to approach the final class, especially with respect to the getInitialState function.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is what I have for the third class:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            stocks = {}
        }

    }
    getData() {
        var stocks = {};
        feed.watch(['MCD', 'BA', 'BAC', 'LLY', 'GM', 'GE', 'UAL', 'WMT', 'AAL', 'JPM']);
        feed.onChange(function(stock) {
            stocks[stock.symbol] = stock;
            this.setState({stocks: stocks, last: stock});
        }.bind(this));
        return {stocks: stocks};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <StockTable stocks={this.state.stocks} last={this.state.last}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must replace getInitialState by initializing the state variable in the constructor.

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    state = {stocks}
}
```

If you have to fetch some values to initialize the state properly, you can do it in the componentDidMount method

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetchInfos().then( infos => this.setState({...infos}) );
}
```

Comment: I updated the OP with what I have for the third class now, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `stocks` in your constructor since you don't have access to it yet (unless you pass down an initial value via `props`). You can initialize it and update the state later, e.g. in `componentDidMount()`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    stocks = {}
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  // fetch stocks and this.setState({ stocks })
}
```

Comment: I updated the constructor at the bottom of the OP. But it still doesn't work. Is there something wrong with the getData() function?

Comment: @thewire Do you get an error? Can you log the `state` inside `render()`?